# Angular, Javascript, PHP

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the html file and the code

```
<ul class="list">
    <li id="numword" data-score="{{item.score}}" class="" ng-repeat="item in words track by $index">
        {{item.word}} {{item.score}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is how it looks in html

```
<li>nice 0.4</li>
<li>sad -0.2</li>
<li>modest 0</li>
```

This is the js file in angular

```
$http.get('select.php') .success(function(data){ $scope.words = data; })
```

This is the database

I have value of words and scores, every word has own score that is in number

My question is: `data-score="{{item.score}}"` i got values of 0.4, 0.2, -0.1, 0...

I need to check if value is greater than 0, equal to 0 and less to 0 in order to add classes to li.

How can i do that ?

Comment: Not sure who down-voted or why exactly but making the description and tags more relevant would help, this question doesn't really have anything to do with PHP you just happen to have a service that is written in PHP but that doesn't affect the angular functionality in any way (one is server side the other is client side, don't mix the two)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `ngClass` attribute for this:

```
ng-class="{positive: item.score > 0, negative: item.score < 0}"
```

This directive is using an object, with *property* as the **class** and  *value* as the **condition**. If the condition is `true`, then the class (which is the property) will be added to the element.

Read more about `ngClass` here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass